# Random monsters move in-sync instead of individually

Tags: xna, c#, algorithm, movement, random

I am making a game in which monsters spawn randomly and begin to move around randomly. I am fairly new at programming but not at game development. Through using a few tutorials I was able to make 1 creature spawn randomly and move randomly (with animations!) in a way that seemed organic instead of robotic.

So, I moved on to the next step of doing this to several creatures. However, when I executed this, I found that instead of executing their own instructions, the rest of the monsters simply mimic the relative movements of 1 central guy. **Everyone moves in sync like some North Korean military parade!**

I am using foreach loops and random numbers to choose their directions. Since my game is a top down 2d isometric, I am using a dictionary to store 4 directions. I have made some changes based on the suggestions here, and now all the creatures animate! But they still don't change directions or do things on their own.

**How do I make them each have their own unique set of instructions instead of everyone just following the dear leader?**

Below is a walkthrough of my code:

Monster Initialization:

```
public void AddCreatures()
{
     NewMonster = new Monster(Texture);
     NewMonster.AddAnimation("northeast", 0, 96, 48, 48, 8, 0.2f);
     NewMonster.AddAnimation("northwest", 0, 144, 48, 48, 8, 0.2f);
     NewMonster.AddAnimation("southeast", 0, 240, 48, 48, 8, 0.2f);
     NewMonster.AddAnimation("southwest", 0, 288, 48, 48, 8, 0.2f);
     NewMonster.AddAnimation("hoon", 144, 336, 48, 48, 1, 1.0f);
     NewMonster.Position = RandomPos();
     NewMonster.DrawOffset = new Vector2(49, 80);
     NewMonster.CurrentAnimation = "southwest";
     NewMonster.IsAnimating = false;
     creatures.Add(NewMonster);
}
```

Spawn:

```
for (int v = 0; v < 12; v++)
{
    AddCreatures();
}
```

Randomize spawn Position:

```
 private Vector2 RandomPos()
        {
            Vector2 location = Vector2.Zero;
            location.X = rng.Next(300,900);
            location.Y = rng.Next(200, 700);
            return location;
        }
```

Movements:

```
 public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timenow += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        foreach (Monster mon in creatures)
        {
            if (mon.IsAnimating)
            {

                if (timenow - (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds > 0.5f)
                {
                    mon.Velocity = directions[rng.Next(1, 5)];
                    ChooseAnim(mon);
                    mon.Velocity.Normalize();
                    speed = (float)(rng.Next(0, 3));
                    diff = new Vector2(mon.Position.X - mon.GetLastPosition.X, mon.Position.Y - mon.GetLastPosition.Y);
                    if (Math.Abs(diff.X) >= 4 && Math.Abs(diff.Y) >= 4)
                    {
                        mon.Velocity = directions[rng.Next(1, 5)];
                        ChooseAnim(mon);
                        mon.Velocity.Normalize();
                    }
                    mon.Velocity.X *= speed;
                    mon.Velocity.Y *= speed;

                    timenow = 0f;
                }
                mon.MoveBy(mon.Velocity);

            }
            DoNotExit();
            mon.Update(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

Animation choosing method:

```
    private void ChooseAnim(Monster mon)
    {
        if (mon.Velocity == directions[1])
            mon.CurrentAnimation = "northeast";
        if (mon.Velocity == directions[2])
            mon.CurrentAnimation = "northwest";
        if (mon.Velocity == directions[3])
            mon.CurrentAnimation = "southeast";
        if (mon.Velocity == directions[4])
            mon.CurrentAnimation = "southwest";

    }
```

Comment: Could you add where you initialize rng?

Comment: Change `foreach (Monster NewMonster in creatures)` to `foreach (Monster monster in creatures)` Then rename all the instances of `NewMonster` inside that loop to `monster`

Comment: I simply initialize rng at the beginning of the Enemy Manager class where all this code is contained.
Random rng = new Random();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very quick way to fix your code. Each monster should have its own `timenow`. The rest of the code can be improved, but is not responsible for the bug you are experiencing.

Once it is done, instead of this:

```
    timenow += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    foreach (Monster mon in creatures)
    {
        ...
```

You do this:

```
    foreach (Monster mon in creatures)
    {
        mon.timenow += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        ...
```

Otherwise when you reset `timenow = 0f` the operation synchronises all monsters.

Comment: Thanks. I changed both timenow and speed into properties of the monster and it works now! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that's everything, but here are some things that look wrong too me:

- Looks like your `oldLoc` variable is common to all your monsters. **It should probably be a member variable of your Monster class**. Otherwise you can't keep a separate record of each monster location.
- You also have a global `thisMonster` and another global `NewMonster`, they seem useless to me, if they're not bringing this bug now, they'll sure bring one later.
- In `ChooseDirection`, you set another global variable `chosen`, and use it afterwards. It's probably not breaking anything for the moment, but simply returning the chosen direction would be a bit cleaner. Otherwise you could be tempted to use this before calling `ChooseDirection` and you'd end up with some more weird issues.
- Less problematic, but still: you're re-initializing your `directions` array at each update, this could be done in an init function, this should event be a static variable.

Moral of the story: [global variables are bad.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) Unless you're a fan of unexpected military parades.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like some very solid advice. I'll see what I can do and report back later.

Comment: 1) done
2) I have removed thisMonster but I need NewMonster in order to initialize i think.
3) I think this method is the key to the problem. I have made some changes including the one you suggested and now the creatures all animate instead of standing still. They still dont change directions though.
4) done

Comment: Weird... I can't see anything else. Do you mean you still have all your monsters changing direction at the same time? Post a Youtube video maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Well, where are you deciding the random movement? This is a symptom of creating multiple `Random`(the class) instances at the same time. They'll all have the same seed time (probably some differing in just a little).
You can usually fix this by instead of creating a `new Random()` for every class that needs random moves, you can just create one `Random` object in your "management class(or something like that) and pass by reference to the classes that will use it.  And I think your flaw is in the `RandomPos()` method or in the Monster constructor.

Something like this:

Instead of this:

```
Vector2 RandomPos()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    return new Vector2(rand.nextInt(x1, x2), rand.nextInt(y1, y2) );
}
```

or this:

```
Monster(Texture2D texture)
{
    this.rand = new Random();
    ///blablabla define movement with rand object.
}
```

you should use:

```
Vector2 RandomPos(Random rand)
{
    return new Vector2(rand.nextInt(x1, x2), rand.nextInt(y1, y2) );
}
```

or this:

```
Monster(Texture2D texture, Random rand)
{
    this.rand = rand;
    ///blablabla define movement with rand object.
}
```

With this example, rand should be created in `AddCreatures()` and shared by all calls of the RandomPos function or Monster constructor.

Comment: I am only initializing random once at the beginning of my Enemymanager class.

Random rng = new Random();
I also added randompos to the original post.